# How to get default export out of vm.SourceTextModule?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Trying the new [SourceTextModule](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_class_vm_sourcetextmodule) API, I'm trying to extract my exports.

Here's what I've got:

```js
async function loader() {
    // ...

    const context = vm.createContext({
        require: filename => {
            return filename;
        },
        module: {
            exports: {},
        }
    });
    const mod = new vm.SourceTextModule(source, {
        context,
        identifier: module.identifier(),
    });

    async function linker(specifier, referencingModule) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to resolve dependency: ${specifier}`);
    }

    await mod.link(linker);

    const result = await mod.evaluate();

    console.log("RESULT", result);
}
```

Where `source` is:

```js
var manifest = {
  name: "MyApp",
  // ...
};
export default manifest;
```

This is printing

```
RESULT [Object: null prototype] { result: undefined }
```

How can I get access to that `export default`? i.e., I want that `manifest` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mod.namespace`....